# Can't define functions in Python

Tags: python, function, python-3.4

Whenever I write a function and then run it in the Shell, it comes up blank. I have only been programming for about a month so don't make things very difficult.

My code looks like this:

```
def intro():

   print("hello world")
```

Then when I run it, it . No air message pops up. Except in my code the 2 lines are touching

Comment: How are you invoking the function?

Comment: Can you write how you call it from the shell? are you defining it in a  file (for example `example.py`) and then importing it?

Answer (score 6):

You wrote a function; now you have to tell it to run the function!

Try

```
def intro():                # <= this tells Python what "intro" means
    print("hello, world")

intro()                     # <= this tells Python to actually do it
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your function!  Do this with `intro()` after the function is defined (Hugh has a nice example above my answer).  Better read up on some basics first ;)  [Codeacademy](http://www.codecademy.com/dashboard) has an awesome Python course if you're interested.